# DATETIME arithmetic in Informix

Tags: informix

I have this piece of code in our Informix stored procedure.

```
if (last_date + 2 units second) > CURRENT then
    raise exception -746,0, "Please try later";
end if
```

I am struggling to understand what is happening here. The `last_date` is a `DATETIME` variable. Is it adding 2 seconds to `last_date`, or 2 days?

Could anybody explain what is happening here please?

Comment: ummm, why would it add 2 days? You are telling it to use 'second' as the unit. Run something like "select current, current + 2 units second, current + 2 units day from table(set{1});" and see the output.

Comment: The code is clearly adding `2 UNITS SECOND`, which is a circumlocuitous way of saying "add 2 seconds".  What the result is depends on which sub-species of DATETIME variable `last_date` is.  If it is, for example, DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND, then you might have a sensible time component; if it is DATETIME YEAR TO DAY, then you won't have a sensible time component (the time component after the addition will be 2 seconds past midnight).  Plain CURRENT maps to DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(3).  So, for better or worse, the code is insisting that the `last_date` value is at least 2 seconds ago.